# Fortran ASSOCIATE syntax to allow indexed access?

Tags: fortran

Is there a nice way to write a Fortran ASSOCIATE statement to turn this

```
FORALL (i = 2:n-2)
    v(:,i) = v(:,i) + MATMUL(A, &
             c(2)*u(:,i-2) + c(1)*u(:,i-1) + c(0)*u(:,i) + c(1)*u(:,i+1) + c(2)*u(:,i+2))
END FORALL
```

into something like the following

```
ASSOCIATE ( U => ..., V => ...)
    FORALL (i = 2:n-2)
        V(i) = V(i) + MATMUL(A, &
               c(2)*U(i-2) + c(1)*U(i-1) + c(0)*U(i) + c(1)*U(i+1) + c(2)*U(i+2))
    END FORALL
END ASSOCIATE
```

I'm staring at Adams et al's *The Fortran 2003 Handbook* section 8.2, but I can't see how to write the `associate-name => selector` construct to allow for indexed access into the `associate-name`.

Obviously what I'm going for is overkill for a couple of lines.  I've got a bunch of 'em that I'd like to condense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misreading things, I don't think this is possible. The [specification](http://www.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/open/n3661.pdf) says (section 8.1.4.3):

> Within a SELECT TYPE or ASSOCIATE construct, each associating entity has the same rank as its
>   associated selector.

and as far as I can see, you want a rank 1 associating entity (`V`) and will need a rank 2 
associated selector (to hold `v`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andrew.  Short of playing preprocessor games, is there any standard idiom to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: @Rhys: I think that the idiom would be to use pointers to array sections, but I don't think that that is going to make your code more comprehensible or neater or shorter, which seem to be your objectives.

Comment: @Mark: I completely agree with pointers to array sections not making it any nicer.  Thanks fellas.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to make the code shorter/nicer, I think the best way to achieve that does not need an `ASSOCIATE` construct:

```
forall(i=2:n-2)
  v(:,i) = v(:,i) + MATMUL(A,MATMUL(u(:,i-2:i+2),c([2,1,0,1,2]))
end forall
```

which, as long as the 5-sized coefficient array does not change, could be preinitialized as a

```
real :: c5(5)
c5 = c([2,1,0,1,2])
```

And then run in a single line as

```
forall(i=2:n-2) v(:,i) = v(:,i) + MATMUL(A,MATMUL(u(:,i-2:i+2),c5))
```

note that it must be `lbound(u,2)<=0`.